Clarification needed regarding the definition of a genral solution of a first order PDE.
While studying PDEs, I was having difficulty in understanding  the following paragraph from the book, " Linear Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers" by Lokenath Debnatha and Tyn Myint-U.

We consider a system of geometrical surfaces described by the equation
$$f (x,y,z,a,b)=0,\tag{(2.3.1)}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary parameters. We differentiate $(2.3.1)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ to obtain $$f_x +pf_z =0, f_y +qf_z =0\tag{2.3.2},$$ where $p = \frac{∂z}{∂x}$ and $q = \frac{∂z}{∂y}.$

The set of three equations $(2.3.1)$ and $(2.3.2)$ involves two arbitrary parameters $a$ and $b.$ In general, these two parameters can be eliminated from this set to obtain a first-order equation of the form
$F (x,y,z,p,q)=0\tag{(2.3.3)}$
Thus the system of surfaces $(2.3.1)$ gives rise to a first-order partial differential equation $(2.3.3).$ In other words, an equation of the form $(2.3.1)$ containing two arbitrary parameters is called a complete solution or a complete integral of equation $(2.3.3).$
On the other hand, any relationship of the form
$f (φ,ψ)=0,\tag{2.3.4}$ which involves an arbitrary function $f$ of two known functions $φ = φ(x,y,z)$
and $ψ =ψ(x,y,z)$ and provides a solution of a first-order partial differential equation is called a general solution or general integral of this equation. Clearly, the general solution of a first-order partial differential equation
depends on an arbitrary fuhction.

Now, it seems that if  $\phi$ and $psi$ are two solutions of $(2.3.3)$ then, $ F (x,y,\phi,p,q)=0=F(x,y,\psi,p,q).$
Now, according to the definition of a general solution as provided in the quoted text, it seems that any arbitrary function $f$ chosen such that $f(\phi,\psi)=0$ maybe considered as a general solution. In other words, we just need to connect $\phi$ and $\psi$ in some way or another to arrive at a general solution of $(2.3.3).$
I hope my understanding up until this point is correct.
The remaining part in the book is as follows:
We obtain the general solution of $(2.3.3)$ from  its complete integral (2.3.1) as follows. First, we prescribe the second parameter $b$ as an arbitrary function of the first parameter a in the complete solution (2.3.1) of (2.3.3), that is, $b = b(a).$  We then consider the envelope of the one-parameter family of solutions so defined. This envelope is represented by the two simultaneous
equations $$f (x,y,z,a,b(a)) = 0,\tag{(2.3.5)}\\$$ $$f_a (x,y,z,a,b(a)) + f_b (x,y,z,b(a))b (a)=0,\tag{(2.3.6)}$$
where the second equation $(2.3.6)$ is obtained from the first equation $(2.3.5)$ by partial differentiation with respect to a. In principle, equation $(2.3.5)$ can
be solved for $a = a(x,y,z)$ as a function of $x, y,$ and $z.$ We substitute this result back in (2.3.5) to obtain $f {x,y,z,a(x,y,z), b(a(x,y,z))} =0,\tag{(2.3.7)}$ where $b$ is an arbitrary function. Indeed, the two equations (2.3.5) and (2.3.6) together define the general solution of (2.3.3).

Now, my question is:
The general solution $f {x,y,z,a(x,y,z), b(a(x,y,z))} =0$ must match with the form of the general solution mentioned previously in the definition, i.e

any relationship of the form
$f (φ,ψ)=0,\tag{2.3.4}$ which involves an arbitrary function $f$ of two known functions $φ = φ(x,y,z)$
and $ψ =ψ(x,y,z)$ and provides a solution of a first-order partial differential equation is called a general solution or general integral of this equation.

Now, I presume that in $f {x,y,z,a(x,y,z), b(a(x,y,z))} =0$ we have $\phi=a$ and $\psi=b$ in line with the definition above. But can we really call $b$ to be a known function? This is because, $b$ is simply an arbitrary function and hence, it might be anything.
